# Using pointers in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to write a function that converts int to byte with the following manner:

```
int * key = convertTo8bits(255);
for(int i = 0; i<8; i++)
cout<<key[i]<<endl;
```

This returns unexpected output. The array that it prints out is made of absurdly large numbers, whereas this works perfectly fine:

```
int * convertTo8bits(int x)
{
int total = 0;
int key[8];
for(int i = 0; i<8; i++)
    key[i] = 0;
if(total + 128 <= x)
{
    key[7] = 1;
    total += 128;
}
if(total + 64 <= x)
{
    key[6] = 1;
    total += 64;
}
if(total + 32 <= x)
{
    key[5] = 1;
    total += 32;
}
if(total + 16 <= x)
{
    key[4] = 1;
    total += 16;
}
if(total + 8 <= x)
{
    key[3] = 1;
    total += 8;
}
if(total + 4 <= x)
{
    key[2] = 1;
    total += 4;
}
if(total + 2 <= x)
{
    key[1] = 1;
    total += 2;
}
if(total + 1 <= x)
{
    key[0] = 1;
    total += 1;
}

for(int i = 0; i<8; i++)
    cout<<key[i]<<endl;

return key;
}
```

Can you point out my mistake ? Thx.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are returning a pointer to a local variable (the array `int key[8]`).  This is **undefined behaviour**, because the local variable goes out of scope (i.e. its lifetime ends) when the function completes.

In C++, you could use a `std::vector<int>` instead of a raw array, because you can return it by value, rather than via a pointer.

---

<sub>I initially thought this was a C question, in which case my initial answer would have been appropriate:</sub>

You have a number of possible solutions:

- Dynamically allocate the array with `malloc`.  (This isn't great, because you'll have to remember to `free` it at some point.)
- Pass a pointer to an array in as a function argument, and write the results to that array.
- Declare `typedef struct { int x[8]; } key;`; you can then return a struct by value rather than via a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Oli has correctly identified the cause of your problem. I think it is also worth pointing out that your code is needlessly complex. You can write it more easily with a loop and bitwise shifting:

```
void extractbits(int x, int key[], int len)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<len; i++)
    {
        key[i] = x & 1;
        x >>= 1;
    }
}
```